# Existing UART libraries on pic/atmega/

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart

I am still new on electronics (my background is software), I played around a bit with Arduino, and I am trying to advance on other microcontrollers like PIC, ARM, etc.

Can I rely on existing libraries to use peripherals like UART, I2C, SPI as I am used to with Arduino?

I googled around for a bit, and pages like [this](https://www.exploreembedded.com/wiki/Serial_Communication_with_PIC16F877A) detail how I can implement UART on a PIC16. So I was wondering, does microchip (or any other microcontroller vendor) have libraries readily available which I can simply include as I was used to with Arduino? Or am I supposed to learn all the low level registers and implement them myself? (because that sounds quite challenging for a beginner like me).

Hope I won't get burned over this question, but couldn't find the answer googling...

Comment: Yes, they have libraries and drivers, although using them isn't as "easy" as Arduino. Take a look at [MPLab X](https://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-x-ide), [Code Configurator](https://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-code-configurator) and [Harmony (for 32-bit MPU's)](https://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-harmony).

Comment: This question is really too broad and at least potentially a prohibited search for off-site resources like libraries. But yes, many MCU vendors publish libraries for basic peripherals and in at least some cases these are fairly popular.  There are also various other multi-platform frameworks beyond Arduino, each having its own compromises.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, and sorry for the poor question. I am looking for a microcontroller that supports (the infamous?) 9 bit uart. And I was hoping that I could also rely on an existing library that allows me to configure 9 bit uart. But the amount of microcontrollers is quite overwhelming and I have no idea which vendor would be my safest bet for this specific requirement. Is the best way forward to just 'buy a bunch and try it out'? I mean, the fact that a microcontroller supports 9 bit uart doesn't mean that the library allows me to configure it (as I found out with arduino)

Comment: You can bit-bang a 9-bit UART protocol if you wanted to using a uC, and that would work with pretty much any microcontroller depending on the timing (rate) you need, including Arduino (would require a small modification to the `SoftwareSerial` library).

Comment: Wouldn't bit banging be less robust than using the actual hardware peripheral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to use the UART in a PIC 16 is to work with the [MCC](https://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-code-configurator). I guess you also could use it as a 9 Bit UART.
But even if you use the MCC you had to learn a little bit more about the hardware than using an Arduino.